# Problema al ejecutar bash con Cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, cronjobs

Actualmente tengo un código que crea un `csv` a partir de una base de datos. Este archivo se ejecuta a través de un **bash**. Si lo ejecuto desde la consola manualmente desde la ubicación del archivo, lo genera sin problema, pero si se programa un ***cronjob*** con este bash, no se ejecuta.

El comando que del cronjob es el siguiente:

```
/home/get/./generatecsv.sh
```

Comment: tal y como te comentan, muestra por favor el contenido de `crontab -l`, así como el contenido del script. Hay muchos posibles motivos para este problema

Answer (score 3):

Verifica que el usuario con el que ejecuta el crontab tenga suficientes permisos para ejecutarlos y que el archivo tengo el permisio de ejecucion.

Por favor comparte el resultado del siguiente comando:

```
crontab -l
ls -la /home/get/./generatecsv.sh
```

Comment: Hola! Cuando ejecuto el comando me manda el "No output generated", el cronjob lo estoy ejecutando desde root

Comment: Por favor puedes compartir la manera en la que ejecutas el script de manera manual y tambien muestra donde tienes configurado el cron por favor.
Que sistema operativo utilizas?

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba primero si tienes permisos de ejecución sobre el script. Si no lo tuvieras, dáselos.

```
chmd +x /home/get/./generatecsv.sh
```

¿Cómo estás introduciendo el crontab? Prueba a introducirlo con el comando:

```
crontab -e
```

Puedes revisar que se haya añadido con

```
crontab -l
```

Y añade:

```
* * * * * /home/get/./generatecsv.sh
```

(Este se ejecutará cada minuto).

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo [aún no puedo comentar para preguntar] que cuando lo corres manualmente estás en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra, o en la carpeta superior, es posible que el script use datos que están en carpetas específicas y por eso no genera nada al correrlo desde cron.

Si este es el caso, tendrías que cambiar de directorio dentro del script o usar la ruta completa del archivo.